# Static HTML/CSS/JS front end & Node.js back end on a live server... HOW?

Tags: node.js, express

I hope one of you can help me with this since I'm **really** struggling:

I have developed a static website locally (on Ubuntu 20.04). The website uses a node.js file (app.js) and some node nodules.

Locally the app.js lives outside the "public" folder along with the package.json and the node modules. When I run "npm run dev", the file spins up a virtual server (localhost:5000).

For the static site to be able to use the stuff inside of the app.js (sending emails with nodemailer, and connecting to mailchimp via the mailchimp api), I have to access the site through the localhost:5000.

EDIT: In my html-files, I have a form that POST to the endpoint '/subscribe', an endpoint that is picked up by the app.js file for further processing by express, and the mailchimp api.

When I'm on local, everything works as it should.

**Now to the question:** How do I make this work on a live server?

The static files are online in a "public" folder on the server and the front end works fine.

EDIT: I'm on a VPS running Ubuntu 20.04, Openlitespeed and the latest versions of node and npm.

Comment: The server will have to be running Node as well. Heroku has a good guide on how to do this on their platform: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on a VPS running Openlitespeed.

Comment: a terminology note: a static site means that your site is literally just a bunch of files. You might _generate_ those using Node, but the resulting generated data is "just files" that you put anywhere that you can host from, without having to run Node.js for things to work. If that's really what you have: just put it in you VPS's public dir, and done. If it's not, then you don't have a static site, you have a Node based website, and given that you're talking about "app.js", probably an Express website (which you'll want to tag your question with, in that case).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the heads up about Express. I've added the tag. But my site is static .html, .css and .js files. The only thing I use node/express for, is to handle api calls and nodemailer transports. Nothing in the DOM is generated by the app.js.

Comment: still you the site is dynamic. One way is to separate the api server which is dynamic and the static side. deploy them separately. or as you mentioned you already have a server, then whats the point of the question ? you can deploy it as it is.. maybe use forever or pm2 to run it in background on port 80.

Comment: @anees I've tried running it with pm2, but it doesn't seem to "link" up with my **dynamic** front end...

Comment: I think I get it now. Users of the site has to access it through the "server" spun up by the app.js ... right?

Comment: serve using express static and use forever process